# Is there any way to clear cache programmatically in angular 7 application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which lazy loads the images.For the first time when my page loads then at that time the images are displayed using lazy loading but if I refresh or reload or close and then open the tab then my images are pre loaded because it is now fetched from cache.Is there any way i can stop caching of my component in angular 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache is not being done by Angular but your browser. Once you load an image (and depending on the headers of the response) your browser will cache it to be able to load it faster the next time. This is usually a good approach.

Not sure why you don't want them to be cached but you have different options. Here you have a good read about HTTP caching: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching This cache configurations for static assets are usually done by your web server and they depend on which webserver you are using (nginx, Apache, IIS, node, ...).

Another option is to append a random query string to your image URL. This HTTP cache system works by using the image URL as a resource key to identify it. Because of this reason you can do something like:

```
<img src="./yourimagefolder/yourimage.jpg?r=putherearandomstring">
```

In this way your image resource 'Id' will be different in each request. (You will need to change the 'putherearandomstring' string in the example with a different random string each time the page is loaded.

Comment: I have a doubt.If my images are cached after loading for the first time.Won't it decrease the performance of my application after caching the data?

Comment: Decrease? No, cache systems are built to improve the performance. The images will be cached in your user browser (not in your server) and the next time they will just load them from their cache instead of hitting your server which will make your app faster.

Comment: You can take a look to mostly every page on internet and check that they are caching the images to improve the page loading speed.

Comment: So, if you think that my answer is correct, could you choose it as the proper answer and upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for development purposes, you can disable the cache in developer tools. I don't see a reason you would want to do this for a live site though? As you would be forcing the user to grab the images everytime they load the component which will reduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with cache in an environment where custom software is updated frequently and some users are less savvy is that they will not automatically get critical client-side changes unless they are told specifically to refresh their cache.  With all of the decorations in the index.html I have not yet found a reliable solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30079442)

Comment: artberri rebuts the entire question by saying that he does not know why clearing the cache would be done.  My answer was explaining while Enterprise developers may need to do so.  I disagree with your flagging my comment.